# Tmux name window at creation and use the name in zsh command

Tags: zsh, tmux

Currently, in my `tmux.conf` I have the following binding which allows me to name a window when I create a new one. Then the window opens in the same directory I was in the last window:

```
# Name windows before you create them
bind-key c command-prompt -p "window name:" "new-window -c '#{pane_current_path}'; rename-window '%%'"
```

I want to achieve the following instead:
When I type the name, it will create the window and execute a bash command like `z <TYPED_NAME>` - the idea is that it will use the name I typed to search for the most relevant directory (using the `z` command for example) and cd into it. Can that be achieved?
If no relevant directory is found with `z` it will use the current behaviour which is to cd into the current path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One problem is that only the first `%%` in the template is replaced. The other is that a `cd` command done in a subshell will be lost when you return to the parent shell. For bash you can try a binding something like this:

```
bind-key c command-prompt -p "window name:" \
  "new-window -c '#{pane_current_path}' 'myfn \"%%\"'"
```

This runs a bash script `myfn` that must be in your PATH to do the work. It contains:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
name=$1
tmux rename-window "$name"
cd ../"$name" || echo "failed to cd to $name" >&2
exec bash -i
```

Remember to `chmod +x` the script. It calls tmux to rename the window, and then you would have your `z` code to find and cd to a directory. In this example, I just look in `../` for it. The final `exec` ensures we replace the current shell by an interactive one.

For zsh, you can do something similar, but if you want `myfn` to be found in your `fpath` you need `new-window` to run zsh with the `-i` option, as zsh only does this for interactive shells. So use a binding like

```
bind-key c command-prompt -p "window name:" \
   "new-window -c '#{pane_current_path}' 'exec zsh -ic \"myfn %%\"'"
```

Here I've added an `exec` to avoid having a pointless parent shell, and since `-c` must be followed by the command as a single string I've put `myfn` and `%%` inside the same double-quotes. You'll need to add more quoting if your name can contain whitespace etc.

The `myfn` zsh script can be the same, with `bash` replaced by `zsh`.
I don't know enough about zsh to avoid the final `exec zsh -i` which is needed to stop the `zsh -ic` shell from terminating.

Comment: I'm sorry I should've mentioned that I have zsh and not bash. The principal should be the same as far as I understand. I did defined a zsh function like `myfn` which works if I type `myfn proj1` -> this renames the current window to proj1 and cd to the correct folder, but then if I bind this as you wrote above, I get in tmux status bar `Unknown Command: myfn "proj1"`, Why is that? I have the functions folder appended to `fpath` and the function auto-loaded correctly (it works as a zsh command in a terminal)

Comment: I've updated my answer with a second part for zsh. zsh will not look for myfn unless it is an interactive shell, and tmux doesnt use one for `new-window`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works! It's a little bit slow but it's better than nothing...